# (Google Developers)Does Deleting google account provide callback to the all the apps to which we login via google account

Tags: java

(Google Developers)Does Deleting google account provide callback to the all the apps to which we login via google account?

If we are deleting a google account, does google sends the callback to all the app which are linked to it for instance any thirdparty sign,  which we do with the help of google account like cleartrip, oracle login or makemy trip etc.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no callback for this. I don't even think there's a way to check an account still exists without having the user sign in again.

Comment: I am using oauth to login into my services using google account, so if user delete it google account, does my service will get any callback from the google that user account is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not work that way. The login process for an app is one way, meaning that the app will send login information to Google and Google will either provide a valid user or not.

Comment: I am using oauth login to login into my services using google account, so if user delete it google account, does my service will get any callback from the google that user account is deleted

Comment: @mckmck As they said in their answer, no you won't.